# Need help about the Dropdown mobile menu transition effect in jquery

Tags: jquery, transition

Can anyone help me make a jquery effect transition for the mobile menu. My goal is when we click the burger menu the drop down should show a transition like fade in effect and when we toggle close the menu it should also be animated the same transition effect fade out. I did made a jquery but somehow it's not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.mk-nav-responsive-link').click(function(){
        $('.mk-responsive-wrap').slideToggle('slow');
    });
 });
```

This is the website which is currently in development http://incredible.phgserver1.com/

Comment: Ok, so my first question would be, you say you want a fade in and fade out, but you're doing a slideToggle.  This is confusing me a bit.  http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/  The api lists the effects methods it offers.  Two of which are fadeIn and fadeOut, and also fadeToggle

Comment: Sorry i used the slideToggle. i was kinda confused doing multiple tests. but yes i want a fading in and out animation. You have to forgive me i am not good in jquery. I don't know how to do it since i barely do jquery scripts.

Comment: It's all good.  I just want to encourage you to browse the library api for documentation on what you need.  The API exists to detail what the library offers, and can help you find the methods you need, potentially avoiding the need to ask a question.

Comment: The problem is when i click open the mobile menu the fade works but when i close it doesn't anymore close the menu :( jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.mk-nav-responsive-link').click(function(){
        $('.mk-responsive-wrap').fadeIn();
    });
 });

Comment: Because you're using `fadeIn()`.  That only fades in.  Read the documentation for `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()` and `fadeToggle()` and see what the differences are.

Comment: Thank you i appreciate much your suggestion. but i think i didn't explain much perfectly on what my goal is.